# importing 2 million rows in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a csv file with more than 2 million rows and i want to create a new table in oracle sql importing the csv file but it gives me error overhead limit exceeded.

How can I import quickly a csv file? I have to try INSERT mode or another type of export?

I expect to create a table with the csv data

Comment: What's the actual error message? And version of sqldev? This should just work.

Comment: "or another type of export" - where is the CSV coming from? If you're generating it from a database, have you looked at datapump export/import?

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I'd use **SQL*Loader**. It is really, *really* fast.

This is 19c [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html#GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144) (basic functionalities didn't change much (if at all) so - have a look. If your database version differs, find appropriate documentation).

Shortly:

- you'd install that utility (maybe you already have it? Check by executing `sqlldr` on your operating system command prompt)
- create control file (which instructs the utility where is source data (in that CSV file), what is target (table you'd create in schema), how to map source data to table columns, etc.)
- run `sqlldr`, specify control (and log) file
- wait until it is over

For testing purposes, maybe you shouldn't load 2 million rows at once - extract a small portion so that you'd be able to test what you did and - once it is OK - load the whole file.

Comment: And you can use sqldev to setup that sqlldr scenario

Comment: Or create an External Table. Gives you the option to parallelize the load easily

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous comment if you want performance, you can t be faster than using DBLoader. As for your error : overhead limit exceeded. It seems to me that you are exceeding the JVM memory (need a more complete trace to confirm). You shouldn't load the full CSV in memory before inserting it, you should read & insert on the fly.